# Is $f$: $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ increasing in a neighboorhood of $f$ if it is increasing in two directions?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am following my 3rd course in Real Analysis and I'm currently dealing with the extrema of functions $f$: $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $f$: $\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and I was wondering if the following holds, I've been trying for hours now to find a proof but I'm unable to, so I'm not sure if it always holds or not.

My conjecture:

Let $f$: $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function, $(x_0, y_0)$ be a value on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

If for any $\epsilon > 0$ small enough (so there exists an $\xi > 0 $ s.t. for any $\epsilon \in (0, \xi $ ) ) we have that both $f(x_0 + \epsilon, y_o) - f(x_0, y_0) \geq 0$ and $f(x_0, y_0 + \epsilon) - f(x_0, y_0)\geq 0$.

Then for any $\alpha > 0, \beta > 0$ if there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ small enough that satisfies the same conditions as above s.t. $\alpha ^2 + \beta^2 \leq \epsilon^2$ then we have that $f(x_0 + \alpha, y_o + \beta) - f(x_0, y_0) \geq 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to consider
$$
f(x, y) = -xy,
$$
at the origin $(x_0, y_0) = (0,0)$, with $\alpha = \beta = 1$.

Comment: I changed my original post, I used $\beta$ twice unintentionally and changed one to $\xi$, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Even after the change, my example shows that your conjecture is false. Pick $\xi = 1$, for example; the first paragraph's conditioin is clearly satisfied, because $f(0 + u, 0) - f(0,0) = -u\cdot 0 + o \cdot 0 = 0 \ge 0$ for **any** $u$, hence certainly for those between $0$ and $1$ (and similarly for the $y$-coordinate).  But in the second paragraph, picking $\alpha = \beta = \epsilon/2$, we get $f(0+\alpha, 0 + \beta) - f(0,0) = -\alpha\beta - 0 = -\alpha^2 = -\epsilon^2/4 < 0.$

Comment: You're 100% correct! Now I'm wondering, is there a condition I could add that would make the conjecture true or does it seem like it is flawed and doomed to fail?

Comment: Does this hold?

$f$: $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable, $(x_0, y_0)$ a value on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

If for any $\epsilon > 0$ small enough (so there exists an $\xi > 0 $ s.t. for any $\epsilon \in (0, \xi $ ) ) we have that both $f(x_0 + \epsilon, y_o) - f(x_0, y_0) > 0$ and $f(x_0, y_0 + \epsilon) - f(x_0, y_0) > 0$.

Then for any $\alpha > 0, \beta > 0$ if there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ small enough that satisfies the same conditions as above s.t. $\alpha ^2 + \beta^2 \leq \epsilon^2$ then we have that $f(x_0 + \alpha, y_o + \beta) - f(x_0, y_0) > 0$.

Comment: (1) THat's a separate question, so you should ask it as a separate question, and (2) it's pretty vague. You could, for instance, add the condition that for all $\alpha, \beta$ of the kind you specified, you get f(x_0 + \alpha, y_o + \beta) - f(x_0, y_0) \geq 0$. From **that**, it's very easy to get to your conclusion, because it's one of your assumptions. :( So while the question might be interesting, it'll be very hard to make it a good MSE question.

Comment: I will ask it as a separate question then, thanks a lot for you help!

Comment: Strict-inequality version: still no. Let $f(x, y) = -100xy + (x^2  + y^2)$.

Comment: So then $f(\epsilon, 0) - f(0,0) = \epsilon^2 > 0$ and $f(0, \epsilon) - f(0,0) = \epsilon^2 > 0$, so the conditions are met. So then with $\alpha = \epsilon / 2, \beta = \epsilon / 2$ we have $f(\epsilon / 2, \epsilon / 2) - f(0,0) = -25 \epsilon^2 + \epsilon^2 / 2 = -49 \epsilon^2 / 2 \leq 0$. So you're correct! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I have thought of the following Lemma:

$\exists \xi > 0 : \forall \epsilon \in (0, \xi): f(x_0 + \epsilon, y_0) - f(x_0, y_0) \geq 0$ then $f_x(x_0,y_0) \geq 0$.

Which has the contrapositive equivalent:

$f_x(x_0,y_0) < 0$ then $\forall \xi > 0 : \exists \epsilon \in (0, \xi): f(x_0 + \epsilon, y_0) - f(x_0, y_0) < 0$. I)

I) clearly holds since if the derivative is less than 0 there must be a point $(x_1, y_0)$ infinitely close to $(x_0, y_0)$ s.t. $x_1 > x_0$ and $f(x_1, y_0) < f(x_0, y_0)$.

But then similarly this also holds for the $y$-direction.

Is this correct?